# Optimize query with temp and while loop and lots of select statement within loop

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, query-optimization

I want to improve the performance of the query which has the records in temp table and am using while loop to access each row from temp table and use it accordingly but there are lots of check in the while loop for which many select statements are there so when there are lots of records say above 300-400, then it takes time as the table for which select statements are used contains records in thousands.

Indexing will slow down the insert DML operations so what all things that can be done here.

Comment: Don't assume that indexes will slow thinsg down. Evidently, lack of indexes is making things slow. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3835/630

Comment: well i am searching on the basis of a column which is not unique so whcih index should i use as non clustered index is slowing things down.